# Azure B2C custom policy brings back expired password even after it is reset

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We are migrating from legacy policies to current ones ahead of the URL deprecation on 31st Aug. We use local account usernames for our users to log in but these have periods in them and this fails the default validation regex so I created a custom policy based off of the samples, [mostly](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-or-email) (although we don't want email used) and modified the regex to allow for periods and longer length. I've uploaded them and some of our test accounts can log in fine.

One of our test accounts comes back with the message: `The password has expired.`  So I log into the Azure B2C portal and reset the password, as we did and worked with the legacy policy.

[image: Screenshot of password reset process]

However we still get the same message when logging in.

The sign in logs affirm the password is expired:

[image: Screenshot of sign in log saying password is expired]

The audit log confirms the password is reset:

[image: Screenshot of confirmation of password reset]

`Block sign in` is set to `no` and the sign-in diagnostic isn't helping, unless I misunderstood it.

PasswordReset_UsernameOrEmail has been uploaded, but doesn't seem to matter. I wonder if TrustFrameworkExtensions_UsernameOrEmail needs amending or I have missed a policy to display the form set the new password?

Here is the user journey from TrustFrameworkExtensions_UsernameOrEmail

```
    <UserJourney Id="PasswordReset_UsernameOrEmail">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSignUp" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountLookup-Combined-PwdReset" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isEmailBoolean</Value>
              <Value>True</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="VerifyEmailForUsernameForPwdReset" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isEmailBoolean</Value>
              <Value>False</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="VerifyEmailAndPassword" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountEmail-PwdReset" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentialsForEmailAcct" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```

Comment: This does look to be the issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/335275/azure-ad-b2c-password-reset-is-not-working.html

Comment: Custom policy will not handle users with forcePasswordChange set to true, that’s what happens if you reset the password through Azure Portal. You need to follow this to support it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/force-password-reset?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Thanks. I have uploaded the SignUpOrSignIn_ForcePasswordReset and it allows people to reset their password, but we don't want to allow signups or FB, just local accounts. We're want to use the SignIn_UsernameOrEmail. Is it possible to copy the ForcePasswordReset elements from that policy into the one we want to use?

Comment: I've had a few goes at this (either stripping the FB and signup from the SignUpOrSignIn policy or adding ForcePasswordReset bits to the SignIn_UsernameOrEmail policy) but keep getting a number of different issues.